# Error while using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am confused, i included the jQuery 1.7 library before executiong this script:

```
var rq;

function request(localTarget, parameter)
{
    $("#" + localTarget).text("Laden...");
    rq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rq.open("GET", parameter, false);
    rq.onreadystatechange = auswerten(localTarget, parameter);
}

function auswerten(target, site)
{   
    if (rq.readyState == 4 && rq.status == 200) {
        $("#" + target).text(rq.responseText);
    } else {
        $("#" + target).text("Wert konnte nicht geladen werden");
    }
}
```

But the Text won't show up, i tried everything, but it won't work!

the Html code i want to insert the text goes like this:

```
<table width='100%' cellpadding='4' cellspacing='0'>
<tr>
  <td class='tablesubheader' width='50%'>Typ</td>
  <td class='tablesubheader' width='50%'>Wert</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Geld heute</td>
<td><div id="money_today">Test</div></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Geld Monat</td>
<td id="money_month"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Klicks heute</td>
<td id="klicks_today"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Klicks Monat</td>
<td id="klicks_month"></td>
</tr>

</table>
</td>
```

The method above is called like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    request('money_today','<?php echo $link1; ?>');
    request('money_month','<?php echo $link2; ?>');
    request('klicks_today','<?php echo $link3; ?>');
    request('klicks_month','<?php echo $link4; ?>');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Where are you calling **request** method in your script?

Comment: above ajax code will work only in IE.

Comment: @MaximilianWalter I modified your code I am using jQuery load.

Comment: i should say that localTarget is a div element and parameter is a url from another website

Answer (score 1):

Move your code inside `$(document).ready` and use .html instead of .text.

modified code: [jquery load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
    function request(localTarget, parameter)
    {
        $("#" + localTarget).("Wert konnte nicht geladen werden");
        $("#" + localTarget).load(parameter);
    }
```

**Note:** you should provide function reference to `rq.onreadystatechange` load not return value of function. `auswerten(localTarget, parameter);` will assign undefined to `onreadystatechange` .

Comment: are you getting any exception?

Comment: erm... lets see: my browser cant prase $('#divelement') to an object. When i just call $('#divelement').html('BlaBla'); nothing apears in the given element, its confusing

Comment: Have checked the element data using developer tools. might be ids are not correct.

Comment: you can't because it has administrative functions. But i can give you the code. And the error that is thrown is: --
[20:44:21.114] TypeError: $("#test") is null @ http://www.*****.biz/manage/hotel/de/housekeeping/index/p/home:2

Comment: $("#test") can not be null as even element is not present  $("#test") will be a object. are you sure $ is jQuery. are you using any other library which use $.

Comment: no i dont, and when i test if jQuery is loaded, it returns true: if(jQuery) { alert("jQuery loaded"); }. I tested it on fiddle and it worked. i dont know why it wont work on my page...

Comment: @Maximilian Walter: What does `alert($)` give? Try `jQuery("#test")`.

Comment: alert($) prints a alert message with a 10 line javascript function, but i tried replacing $ with jQuery and it works now! but the .load('url') wont work, its linking to another .php document with get options, any advices?

Comment: @MaximilianWalter that means $ is getting overridden by somewhere in your code. check if url is correct (try to open directly in browser). see how to use load http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Thanks for for this quick help, you'r all the best <3

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the problem is that your code is running before the elements you're trying to deal with exist on the page: i.e. before the pages is loaded. Try putting that code inside the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rq.onreadystatechange = auswerten(localTarget, parameter);
```

You're calling the function right here. You don't what that - the browser should call the function when the response has arrived:

```
// pass a function (that you don't call), which in turn calls `auswerten`
rq.onreadystatechange = function() {
  auswerten(localTarget, parameter);
};
```

Anyway, jQuery has a built-in `$.ajax` function that has cross-browser normalization and is quicker to use.

Comment: i hate javascript, so please just tell me how to load a text with ajax from a url and paste it to a div element

Comment: @Maximilian Walter: In jQuery that can be done with just `$("#id").load("foo.html")`.

Comment: Ok i got this element on my site:<div id="klicks_month"></div>

Comment: And i execute this code now: $("#klicks_month").load('<?php echo $link4; ?>'); But it sill won't work!

Comment: @MaximilianWalter: I can only guess, so: 1) Use `$(document).ready`, 2) make sure the ID is really correct and the element exists, 3) make sure the file you're loading exists, 4) use a console to check for errors.

Comment: Oh and the link goes like 'site.de/page.php?opt1=1&opt2=2&opt3=3'

Comment: I checked if the files are all loaded, i use $(document).ready and i checked the ids. But still nothing!

Comment: @Maximilian Walter: Well then I'm out of ideas. But do make sure to open up a console to see if any error occurs! There must be happening something exceptional.